# Colorbox: Show/simulate 'loading' animation for iframe content?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

How can I show or simulate (using a fixed timespan) a loading animation for iframe content which is displayed using Colorbox?

What I'd like to achieve is actually a temporary overlay over the iframe content, which disappears when the iframe-content is loaded. Is this somewhat possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [LoadMask](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) plugin that can display an overlay. You will need to control when to show it and when to hide it manually though.

Comment: works beautifully. I 'mask' when the content i supposed to be loaded (but when the iframe loading starts..) and I 'unmask' from the iframe :)