# Page loading animation

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to display a loading animation while my page is loading, and when loading is complete then obviously hide it.

I am working in ASP.NET using Masterpages, just wondering there is a a simple way of doing this using JQuery?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place an image with the animated gif on the page. Give it an id of loadingImage and add the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadingImage').hide();
});
```

Incidentally, how long is your page taking to load? Is it using AJAX calls to load data? Maybe you should look into this and in the callback handler, call the hide() function on your image.

Comment: So simple and interesting , Is there any way while all the page is not loaded completely , The page would be disable ?

Comment: Hi @Mostafa, if you want to disable scripts on your page until loaded, the $(document).ready(function...)  is the place to initialise them. If you want to do more, post a question with more details.

Comment: The page is taking about 5 seconds to load, but in my scenario it is loading in a separate frame so I want some feedback to the user as otherwise you click the link and nothing seems to happen.

I have tried your example code but everything seems to happen at once rather than the loading div appearing then disappearing when the main content is loaded.

I guess a more complex solution is required with some kind of handler. I am using APP.NET AJAX if something can be done with that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx) control

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Link I posted has an example at the bottom of the page

Comment: This looks interesting, but I am not sure how I would wire this up to the page before everything else loads? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When both answers above were along the right lines, I could get either do exactly what I needed in my scenario.

However I found the following post that on SO that has provided me the solution I was after.

[Colorbox: Show/simulate 'loading' animation for iframe content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755041/colorbox-show-simulate-loading-animation-for-iframe-content)

Thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I made an animation in this way on my master page:

```
<div id="loading" style="text-align: center" hidden><asp:Image ID="loadingImage" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Images/loading.gif" /></div>
```

and then I used jQuery in this way

```
<script>
function showLoading() {
    $("#loading").show();
  }

  var loadingTimeout = setTimeout(showLoading, 3000);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    clearTimeout(loadingTimeout); //make sure loader doesn't appear if page loads in less than 3 seconds
    $("#loading").hide();
  });
</script>
```

I hope this will help.